# IOS ManagedObjectContext Placement

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am writing an application which needs data persistance. I am using CoreData as my framework for this. I am currently trying to design my data structures for the app, of which I am planning on having 2.

The main data in my app is a sheet of various information which is input in a wizard format. I wish to use a MutableArray to hold the form data.

Secondly, I wish to have an individual instance (singleton) of MyClass available at any time, which I will use as a temporary placeholder to accept data being input during the wizard. Once the user completes all the steps, it will create a new object in the array for it.

What I gather from CoreData is that I need to use the ManagedObjectContext as a bridge between my application and the disk on the iOS Device. My question is:

"Should I use one instance of this context in the app delegate and just reference to it from any view who needs to talk to the files, or do I make a new context on every ViewController."

Right now I am not fussed on memory efficiency, but I wish to be as efficient as I can before I release the app.

Comment: "Of course, apple want to do things differently to everybody else". Nice way to put off people like me who would otherwise want to help you.

Comment: I dont see the issue, I simply stated why I am having difficulty. My training is in legacy C++, not Objective. I can remove the comment if you wish?

Comment: What has been seen cannot be unseen. Anyway, the Managed Object Context is not a bridge, it's a scratchpad where changes to objects in your persistent store are made before saving. As for new or different contexts for each controller, it depends on whether you are using multithreaded Core Data. It's hard to advise on this as it stands.

Comment: Roger that, thanks a lot.

Comment: You could do worse than learning the basics of Core Data before you try using any of the convenience libraries. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/coreDataOverview.html

Answer (score -1):

If you have a singleton Shared instance as an access layer, you could also make it to be the communicator to your core data context.

I recommend using a UIManagedDocument to setup the managed object context. It is a bit more work at the beginning but for example you could implement iCloud access more easily.

But you can of course also just hold a managedObjectContext (without managed document) in your singleton, or - as in the per designed core data app - in your app delegate (which you can access by the uiapplication  shared instance from anywhere).
There is really not one right way, I think. You could look at the Stanford c193p lectures (available on iTunes) and watch the core data sessions to get to know the managedDocument approach.